# npm package - unsupported engine

Tags: npm

Currently I am in den npm Node version hell.
If I invoke the following command I get the following message:

```
\app>npm install @npmcli/fs
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/architect@0.1200.5',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular-devkit/core@12.0.5',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: {
npm WARN EBADENGINE     node: '^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     npm: '^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6',
npm WARN EBADENGINE     yarn: '>= 1.13.0'
npm WARN EBADENGINE   },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.20.2', npm: '8.19.4' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

Does anyone know what to do in order to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning you are seeing is related to the mismatch between the Node.js and npm versions specified in the package's `package.json` file and the versions that you currently have installed on your system.

The warning is indicating that the packages `@angular-devkit/architect` and `@angular-devkit/core` have specified engine requirements that are not satisfied by your current Node.js and npm versions.

The required engine versions for these packages are:

- `@angular-devkit/architect`: Node.js `^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0`, npm `^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6`
- `@angular-devkit/core`: Node.js `^12.14.1 || >=14.0.0`, npm `^6.11.0 || ^7.5.6`

However, you have Node.js version `16.20.2` and npm version `8.19.4` installed.

You can downgrade your Node.js and npm versions to ones that satisfy the requirements specified in the package's `package.json` file. You can use a tool like `nvm` (Node Version Manager) to manage multiple Node.js versions on your system.

To downgrade Node.js using `nvm` (Node Version Manager), you can follow these steps:

1. **Install `nvm`** (if you haven't already):
   If you don't have `nvm` installed, you can install it by following the instructions on the official GitHub repository: [nvm installation instructions](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installation-and-update)
2. **List Available Node.js Versions**:
   Open a terminal and run the following command to see the list of available Node.js versions that you can install:

   ```bash
   nvm ls-remote
   ```
3. **Choose a Version to Install**:
   Look for a Node.js version that matches the requirements of your project. For example, if your project requires Node.js `14.17.0`, you can install it using:

   ```bash
   nvm install 14.17.0
   ```
4. **Switch to the Installed Version**:
   Once the desired version is installed, you can switch to it using:

   ```bash
   nvm use 14.17.0
   ```

   This will set the active Node.js version to `14.17.0`.
5. **Downgrade npm**:
   After switching to the desired Node.js version, you can use the `npm` command to downgrade npm to a specific version. For example, to downgrade npm to version `6.14.14`:

   ```bash
   npm install -g npm@6.14.14
   ```

   This will install npm version `6.14.14` globally.
6. **Verify Versions**:
   Verify that you have successfully downgraded Node.js and npm by running the following commands:

   ```bash
   node -v
   npm -v
   ```

   These commands should display the version numbers you've switched to and installed.

Comment: The mismatch is only with `npm`  which is required either as version `6.xx` or `7.xx` but the current npm version installed is 8.xx. And "most of the time" such warnings can probably be ignored, especially if you are on a higher major version (ie 8.xx), because typically such restrictions are because of issues that where fixed or features that where introduced with a given minor version. And the newest major version most of the time will contain those too.